# Using boost::shared_ptr with WSACleanup

Tags: c++, boost, wsastartup, wsacleanup

I would like to use a boost::shared_ptr in order for WSACleanup() to be called when my function goes out of scope, like this:

```
void DoSomething() {
    WSAStartup(...);
    boost::shared_ptr<void> WSACleaner(static_cast<void*>(0), WSACleanup);
}
```

This does not compile,

`Error  1   error C2197: 'int (__stdcall *)(void)' : too many arguments for call    C:\projects\svn-5.3\ESA\Common\include\boost\detail\shared_count.hpp    116`

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: "The expression d(p) must be well-formed" (i.e. `WSACleanup(static_cast<void*>(0)` must be well-formed.)

One possible solution:

```
boost::shared_ptr<void> WSACleaner(static_cast<void*>(0),
                                   [](void* dummy){WSACleanup();});
```

Comment: this looks elegant, could you please elaborate on the syntax of `[](void* dummy){WSACleanup();}`

Comment: @tsotso: This is not a site for teaching the basics of C++11.

Comment: @tsotso: If you want to google it, it's called a "lambda expression". It allows you to write a function whereever you can use a function pointer

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal A simple link to [Lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) would have been much more helpful than your inaccurate  statement

Comment: @tsotso: In what way was it inaccurate?

Comment: BTW standard alternative would be `std::unique_ptr<void*, std::function<void(*)(void*)>` - you need to pass the type of the deleter.

Comment: @MSalters: thanks, any way to achieve the same without C++0x syntax? boost?

Comment: @tsotso: For a 20th century solution ;) see rodrigo's comment to jcalvosa answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class `A`which destructor invoques `WSACleanup` and instance of shared_ptr with it:

```
class A
{
    public:
        ~A() { WSACleanup(...); }
}

....

void DoSomething() {
    WSAStartup(...);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> x(new A);
}
```

Comment: But then, you can just create a local variable of that type. And now that you are on it, you can call `WSAStartup` from the constructor.

Comment: @rodrigo yes you are right, but can use it wherever you want in other scope of program.

Comment: Using a class with ctor and dtor is the far cleaner solution. It's also easily extended to situations where you might have multiple sections of code that require network connections, potentially overlapping in time. Just use a private static counter to keep track of the ctor-dtor balance.